# Vectors in a Hilbert space are countably supported with respect to any orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I} \subset \mathcal{H}$ be an orthonormal set in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. For any vector $x\in \mathcal{H},$ let $$I_x=\{i\in I|\,\langle x,e_i\rangle \neq 0\}.$$ How can we check that $I_x$ is countable for any $x\in \mathcal{H}$? Thanks!

Comment: You don´t suppose $\mathcal{H}$ to be separable?

Comment: @Tomek: Kudos for giving this a proper title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sets $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}$
$$ I_{x,n} = \left\{i \in I : \abs{\<x,e_i>} > \frac 1n\right\} $$
By Bessel's inequality, 
$$ |I_{x,n}| \cdot \frac 1{n^2} \le \sum_{i\in I_{x,n}} \abs{\<x,e_i>}^2 \le \|x\|^2 $$
That is $|I_{x,n}| \le n^2 \|x\|^2$ is finite, hence $I_x = \bigcup_n I_{x,n}$ is  countable.

Answer (score 2):

Edit. For some reason I have pressumed that we are talking about orthonormal bases. The argument below still works; all we have to do is to extend this set to an orthonormal basis. Suppose then that $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis.

By [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity),

$$\sum_{i\in I} |\langle x, e_i\rangle|^2 = \|x\|^2.$$

For the left hand side to be finite, $\langle x, e_i\rangle$ can be non-zero for at most countably many $i$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{e_i:i\in \Bbb N\}$ is any orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert Space $H$ then for any $x\in H$ we have $x=\sum _{i=1}^\infty \langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$.

By Bessel's Inequality $||x||^2\ge \sum _{i=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_i\rangle |^2$.

Consider $S_n=\{i\in I:|\langle x,e_i\rangle |^2\ge \dfrac{||x||^2}{n}\}$

Now each $S_n$ has at most $n-1$ elements otherwise it would contradict Bessel's Inequality.